# Unfolded mesh to 3D

Tags: print-design, 3d

I have the following pattern/mesh, when glued together turns into a 6 panel cap. On this mesh I want a continues image printed like seen on a world globe.

How can I place an image inside this pattern/mesh. And when cutout, glued together, it stays one image? It's like reversed UV mapping.

[image: 2d mesh of 3d sphere]

Keywords I tried Googling without any luck: UV mapping, reversed UV mapping, mesh to 3D, continues image on sphere.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello Huig, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: The best approach will be dependent on the actual pattern/image that you want to apply. Can you share the image?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for getting back at me. The image should be easily changed since I want to use different patterns in the future. But to give you an example: https://www.behance.net/gallery/43847067/Patterns-2

Comment: Hi, idk if this is much help and it's a few years since I've used it, but afai remember Rhinoceros 3D have commands exactly for this. Project bitmap image to 3D plane, cut 3D surface and then rollout 3D surfaces to 2D planes.

Comment: @HaraldCFS all 3D applications I have used have this feature, including Maya, 3ds max, modo, rhinoceros, creo, z-brush, Mudbox, hell even Photoshop can do this (though it can not make the model). There are even apps dedicated to only this like Mari. The real question to the OP (original poster) is do you have a 3D model or not. One could offcourse be created but that is not so easy if this is say cloth instead of paper.

Comment: Well that's great @joojaa why don't you recommend the software you would use for this specific task. Here's the workflow I imagine:
1. create complete solid 3D model. 2. map image in 3D software onto model. 3. cut out model to shapes/ roll back to 2D, with images intact. Print out images and transfer, if model is in stiff material, like paper. print out image guides, if this is to be a knitted cap or whatever.
btw, joojaa don't take this the wrong way, but saying 'the real question' sounds illogical. I assume you mean the phrase  'the right question to ask'.

Comment: @HaraldCFS Because i dont know what the real purpose is. The problem with model then cut up is that many, or in fact most, surfaces are impossible to unwrap into 2D. So for it to make sense i would need to know what kind of surface is in question to make an answer. PS: "the real question" is a idom and should be used like that.

Comment: @HaraldCFS thank you so much for helping me out with this one. It is to be knitted. Your answer is I think the closes to a (easy) solution, I already started working on a 3D model to try this out!

@ joojaa  I use a combination of materials, but mostly satin. I think if I can make a 3D object from the mesh, place the image and reverse it back into a mesh it could work. Im learning Blender, any good?

Comment: You're welcome. It's quite possible @jooja sees some hickups down the road that will complicate things, but best of luck anyways.